# Unable to get audio file header with AV Foundation

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, avfoundation, objective-c++

For my application, on one side, I need to get the audio file from the itunes library as it is store on the disk. For that, I have a callback to stream each audio buffer to a client.

On the other side, I have a callback to get those audio buffer and build a playable audio file in the original format as it was store on the ios device.

I've tried for days to get the thing works but without success.
In deed,  on the client side I have an audio file about the original size but without the audio header. This result in an unplayable audio file.

For that I use this piece of code :

1) Open the audio file

```
NSURL* url =
        [ NSURL fileURLWithPath : [ [ NSBundle mainBundle ]
                                          pathForResource : @"test"
                                                   ofType : @"m4a" ] ];

AudioFileOpenURL( ( __bridge CFURLRef ) url,
                   permission,
                   0,
                   & _audioFileId );

NSDictionary* options =
    @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : @YES };
_asset = [ AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL : url options: options ];
```

2) Create an AVAsset

```
NSError* assetError = nil;
_assetReader =
    [ AVAssetReader alloc ] initWithAsset: _asset error: & assetError ];

if( nullptr == _assetReader )
{
    return false;
}

_assetTrack = [ _asset.tracks objectAtIndex:0 ];
```

3) Create an AVAssetOutput configured to read the file as it is on the disk

```
_assetOutput = 
     [ AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack: _assetTrack
       outputSettings:nil ];
```

4) Create a dump file ( just for the test ) and get audioFileDescription

```
std::ofstream saveFile( "/tmp/dump.m4a" );

AudioStreamBasicDescription _audioFileDescription;
UInt32 size = sizeof( description );
const auto ret = AudioFileGetProperty( _audioFileId,
                                       kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat,
                                       & size,
                                       & _audioFileDescription );

if( noErr != ret )
{
    std::memset( & _audioFileDescription, 0, sizeof( _audioFileDescription ) );
}
```

5) Loop to dump the audio file ( same as streaming the audio file on the network )

```
// read and dump the audio file
const CMTime startTime =
     CMTimeMake( 0, _audioFileDescription.mSampleRate * ( _audioFileDescription.mBitsPerChannel / 8 ) * _audioFileDescription.mChannelsPerFrame );
const CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake( startTime, kCMTimePositiveInfinity );
_assetReader.timeRange = range;

[_assetReader addOutput: _assetOutput ];
[_assetReader startReading ];

while( [ _assetReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading )
{
    if( CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [ _assetOutput copyNextSampleBuffer ] )
    {
        // Get samples.
        CMBlockBufferRef audioBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer( sampleBuffer );
        size_t lengthAtOffset;
        size_t totalLength;
        char *samples;
        CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer( audioBuffer, 0, &lengthAtOffset, &totalLength, &samples );

        saveFile.write( samples, totalLength );

        if( ::CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer( sampleBuffer ) )
        {
            // The time of the buffer we received, which should preceed the time we requested
            CMTime presentationTime = ::CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp( sampleBuffer );

            // The time we requested in presentation units
            CMTime requestedTime = [ _assetTrack samplePresentationTimeForTrackTime: startTime ];

            // trim = priming frames + offset into buffer to satisfy our requested time
            CFDictionaryRef trimAtStartDictionary = (CFDictionaryRef)::CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_TrimDurationAtStart, NULL);
            CMTime trimAtStart = trimAtStartDictionary ? ::CMTimeMakeFromDictionary(trimAtStartDictionary) : kCMTimeZero;

            // Therefore, priming frames = trim - offset
            CMTime offset = ::CMTimeSubtract(requestedTime, presentationTime);
            CMTime primingFrames = CMTimeSubtract(trimAtStart, offset);
            printf("Priming frames: ");
            CMTimeShow(primingFrames);
        }

        CFRelease( sampleBuffer );
    }
}

saveFile.close();
```

My conclusion are that AV foundation framework seems to not provide a way to get an audio file header.

If I am correct, is there a way to get those headers differently ?

And if I am wrong, could someone point me to the right way of doing this.

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Jeremy S